# ¿Se puede usar una var ordinal independiente en una regresión logística ordinal?

Tags: r

Estoy haciendo un modelo de regresión logística ordinal en R, pero no sé por qué me cambia los nombres de las variables si pongo una variable ordinal en las varibles independientes de la fórmula al usar polr del paquete MASS. (Supongo tiene sentido que cambien los valores cuando la variable es ordinal):

Por ejemplo con este código, al poner la variable *clarity* como categórica:

```
data(diamonds)

muestra_diamantes <- diamonds[1:100,]
muestra_diamantes$cut <- factor(muestra_diamantes$cut, levels=c('Fair', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Premium', 'Ideal'), ordered=TRUE)
muestra_diamantes$clarity <- factor(muestra_diamantes$clarity, levels=c('I1', 'SI2', 'SI1', 'VS2', 'VS1', 'VVS2', 'VVS1', 'IF'), ordered=FALSE)

muestra_lro <- MASS::polr(formula=cut ~ x + y + z + clarity, data=muestra_diamantes, Hess=TRUE, method="logistic")

exp(coef(summary(muestra_lro)))
```

Coeficientes exponenciados:

```
|                   | Value       | Std Error  | t          |
|-------------------|-------------|------------|------------|
| x                 | 0.127456184 | 124.139126 | 0.65229528 |
| y                 | 12.95810574 | 114.487089 | 1.71668465 |
| z                 | 0.196285788 | 14.70743   | 0.54572311 |
| claritySI2        | 0.63312405  | 4.733888   | 0.7452797  |
| claritySI1        | 0.512574993 | 4.579121   | 0.64452544 |
| clarityVS2        | 0.28127597  | 4.76252    | 0.44366549 |
| clarityVS1        | 0.20029496  | 4.718363   | 0.35472276 |
| clarityVVS2       | 0.454695091 | 4.88625    | 0.60847767 |
| clarityVVS1       | 0.432025719 | 4.807342   | 0.58595175 |
| Fair|Good         | 0.001374046 | 11.163314  | 0.06512454 |
| Good|Very Good    | 0.012629681 | 10.195421  | 0.15216611 |
| Very Good|Premium | 0.072818199 | 9.860981   | 0.3183131  |
| Premium|Ideal     | 0.221585212 | 9.815635   | 0.51695916 |
```

Al poner la variable *clarity* como ordinal:

```
# muestra_diamantes$clarity <- factor(muestra_diamantes$clarity, levels=c('I1', 'SI2', 'SI1', 'VS2', 'VS1', 'VVS2', 'VVS1', 'IF'), ordered=TRUE)

|                   | Value       | Std Error   | t         |
|-------------------|-------------|-------------|-----------|
| x                 | 0.123991625 | 123.701862  | 0.6483718 |
| y                 | 13.31223779 | 113.894553  | 1.7275099 |
| z                 | 0.196626228 | 14.693605   | 0.5459594 |
| clarity.L         | 0.001855322 | 3427798.281 | 0.6583678 |
| clarity.Q         | 0.008909861 | 3816358.193 | 0.7323537 |
| clarity.C         | 0.009782939 | 158278.5153 | 0.6794367 |
| clarity^4         | 0.034829154 | 2709.986301 | 0.6539515 |
| clarity^5         | 0.191235962 | 66.482591   | 0.6742492 |
| clarity^6         | 0.807139755 | 5.494582    | 0.8818299 |
| Fair|Good         | 0.011340425 | 43.987691   | 0.3061142 |
| Good|Very Good    | 0.104355146 | 41.774658   | 0.5457936 |
| Very Good|Premium | 0.601682289 | 41.716317   | 0.8726966 |
| Premium|Ideal     | 1.830864643 | 41.823995   | 1.1758496 |
```

¿Alguien sabe por qué pasa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un comportamiento de [`model.matrix()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/model.matrix.html) que es de las primeras funciones que invoca internamente `MASS::polr()`, desde esta matriz es dónde luego se van a buscar los nombres de cada coeficiente. A modo de ejemplo:

```
df <- data.frame(x=factor(sample(LETTERS[1:6], 100, replace = TRUE), 
                          levels=LETTERS[1:6], ordered = TRUE),
                 y=factor(sample(LETTERS[11:16], 100, replace = TRUE), 
                          levels=LETTERS[11:16], ordered = TRUE)
)

modelo <- model.matrix(y~x, data=df)  
colnames(modelo) 

[1] "(Intercept)" "x.L"         "x.Q"         "x.C"         "x^4"        
[6] "x^5"
```

Como puedes observar, cuando el factor `x` está ordenado, los columnas (que luego serán los nombres de los coeficientes) se denomina con el nombre de la variable independiente más `L` por "linear", `Q` por "Quadratic"  y `C` por "Cubic", el resto se corresponde con el valor numérico de grado de ese término polinómico ([+ info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42501864/column-names-of-ordered-factor-in-model-matrix-in-r)), una razón histórica de diseño.

Por otro lado, si lo que buscas es mantener la misma nomenclatura, puedes hacer algo así:

```
names(muestra_lro$coefficients) <- paste0("clarity",levels(muestra_diamantes$clarity)[-1])[1:length(muestra_lro$coefficients)]
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! O sea básicamente necesito cambiar los _rownames_ de los coeficientes del dataframe que me regresa ```coef()```, menos la categoría de referencia, ¿verdad? algo así: ```nombres_var <- levels(muestra_diamantes$clarity)[-1]; rownames(muestra_lro$coefficients[4:length(nombres_var)]) <- paste("clarity", nombres_var, sep="")```

Comment: Cuidado, me parece que en tu código estás modificando los nombres a partir del 4to grado, pero con los nombres desde el primero.